# Valgrind hangs in pthread_spin_lock consuming 100% CPU

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

My C++ multi threaded application hangs in pthread_spin_lock in valgrind versions 3.8.0 and latest. But it is not happening in 3.6.0, 3.6.1 and 3.7.0. Anyone knows any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is cause the internal problems of thread managing in valgrind. I had same problem and it was fixed in 3.10 version of valgrind.

Comment: Julian Seward has fixed it in 3.9 later release. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336435. Thank you prez.

Answer (score 0):

The issue logged in the valgrind official issue management system. Julian Seward has fixed it in 3.9 later version. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336435